# nginx, deny all other subdomains and IP address

Tags: nginx

I have this nginx config. I want nginx to deny all subdomains except for secure.myserver.com, however this config denys everything, including secure.myserver.com

if I remove the deny block, then my main block works fine.

```
#main
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  listen [::]:443 ssl;
  server_name secure.myserver.com;
}

#deny
server {
  listen 443 default_server;
  server_name _;
  deny all;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your main block, you are defining a `listen` directive for IPv4/IPv6 and then for IPv6 separately.

You should either use of these:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
}
```

in both your `server` blocks.

Furthermore, your second `server` block is missing the `ssl` from the `listen` directive.